# Stop Macro from running on external application

Tags: excel, vba

Pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> many times not working. Can you suggest any ideas that might help me? Sorry for my noobies question, im just new using VBA Excel.

```
Sub CopyText(Text As String)
    'VBA Macro using late binding to copy text to clipboard.
    'By Justin Kay, 8/15/2014
    Dim MSForms_DataObject As Object
    Set MSForms_DataObject = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    MSForms_DataObject.SetText Text
    MSForms_DataObject.PutInClipboard
    Set MSForms_DataObject = Nothing
End Sub


Public Sub proto()

Dim Rrng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim toCopy As String

firstsheetname = "mainWorksheet"
qwe = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rrng = Sheets(firstsheetname).Range("E7:E" & qwe)


AppActivate "*******"

Application.Wait Now + 0.0001
    For Each cel In Rrng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        VbSendKeys "%a"
        toCopy = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & cel.Row).Text
        CopyText toCopy
        Sleep 500
        VbSendKeys "^v"
        Sleep 500
        SendKeys "{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "{TAB}", True
        toCopy = ActiveSheet.Range("F" & cel.Row).Text
        CopyText toCopy
        Sleep 500
        VbSendKeys "^v"
        Sleep 500
        SendKeys "{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "0", True
        SendKeys "{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "0", True
        SendKeys "{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "12", True
        SendKeys "{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "~", True
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can post the code which you are running it would be easier to guess what the answer is.   But in general...

It could be there is one VBA command which is taking a long time and tying up the process, such as when you use office automation.  You can find those by putting a break point (the red circle on left edge of the code window) just before the line you think is slow, then stepping over the code (Shift-F8) one line at a time to see how long each one takes to run.

If it's a tight loop preventing your Break key press from being processed, you could place a `DoEvents` command in the loop.  This briefly halts execution in the thread and makes it more responsive to breaking.

I like to put `Debug.Print "Step 1 starting...": DoEvents` lines throughout a macro to help identify where the code is taking a long time.

Now that I see your code I suspect the call to the Sleep() Windows API function is the issue.  I prefer to keep calls to Sleep short and interruptable.  Try this Pause() subroutine instead.  It calls Sleep() for 2 milliseconds which is enough to avoid thrashing the CPU while it waits but will respond to breaks straight away:

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then ' Office 2010 or later
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As LongPtr)
#Else ' Office 2007 or earlier
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As Long)
#End If

Public Sub Pause(Optional sngSeconds As Single = 0.5)
    'Breakable version of Sleep.  Midnight safe (Timer reverts to zero at midnight)
   Const SECONDS_IN_DAY = 24! * 60! * 60! '! = Single floating point type
   Dim sngStart As Single: sngStart = Timer
   Dim sngEnd As Single: sngEnd = sngStart + sngSeconds
   Dim bTraversesMidnight As Boolean: bTraversesMidnight = (sngEnd >= SECONDS_IN_DAY)
   Dim sngTimer As Single: sngTimer = Timer
   While (Not bTraversesMidnight And (sngTimer < sngEnd)) Or _
             (bTraversesMidnight And (sngTimer + IIf(sngTimer < sngStart, SECONDS_IN_DAY, 0) < sngEnd))
      DoEvents
      Sleep 2 'milliseconds
      DoEvents
      sngTimer = Timer
   Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: im only using sendkeys copy and paste from excel to extenal app with sleep 500 (0.5 secs). Sorry for not including full details.

Comment: @user10182078 as DimRasRecordset already said without the exact code where this happens it is impossible to tell what it is, because there can be more than one reason. If you need a more precise answer than the one here, you will need to edit your question and add the code to reproduce the issue: [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Comment: here you go.. Sorry I had trouble posting my codes

Comment: @user10182078 Exactly what DimRasRecordset wrote in his answer. You have a loop running and there is no time to proced your break command. Put a `DoEvents` into your loop to give Excel the opportunity to process your break there.