# VBA to open webpage then submit data

Tags: html, vba, web

I am very new to IE controlled by vba, but have stumbled by to write the following code, which was pieced together using various online searches.

My issue is that while this code works if a breakpoint is added before the 'click/submit' is clicked (then going to the IE window), it does not seem to update the webpage when it is run without a breakpoint.

If I were to break the code and see where the cursor is on the webpage, then resume the code, it will save and update but i can't seem to get it working normally.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
Sub test()
url = "Sharepoint - hidden"

Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate url
    
    
Dim HTMLDOC As HTMLDocument

Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Do
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDOC = IE.Document


HTMLDOC.all.Item("ctl00_ctl40_g_07433f93_b974_4a29_9e53_cc3a087aa20a_FormControl0_V1_I1_T5").innerText = "New Employee - Test:" & Now()   '[Request Type]
HTMLDOC.all.Item("ctl00_ctl40_g_07433f93_b974_4a29_9e53_cc3a087aa20a_FormControl0_V1_I1_T5").Focus
HTMLDOC.all.Item("ctl00_ctl40_g_07433f93_b974_4a29_9e53_cc3a087aa20a_FormControl0_V1_I1_B3").Click
End sub
```

Comment: Perhaps some time delay is what you need, try [Application.Wait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.wait)? If you are doing this on Excel.

Answer (score 1):

After a few days trying all sorts of solutions, I have found one that works and it is as simple as adding in a couple more .Focus lines as follows:

```
HTMLDOC.all.Item("ctl00_ctl40_g_07433f93_b974_4a29_9e53_cc3a087aa20a_FormControl0_V1_I1_T5").Focus
HTMLDOC.all.Item("ctl00_ctl40_g_07433f93_b974_4a29_9e53_cc3a087aa20a_FormControl0_V1_I1_T5").innerText = "New Employee - Test:" & Now()   '[Request Type]
HTMLDOC.all.Item("ctl00_ctl40_g_07433f93_b974_4a29_9e53_cc3a087aa20a_FormControl0_V1_I1_T5").Focus
HTMLDOC.all.Item("ctl00_ctl40_g_07433f93_b974_4a29_9e53_cc3a087aa20a_FormControl0_V1_I1_B3").Focus
HTMLDOC.all.Item("ctl00_ctl40_g_07433f93_b974_4a29_9e53_cc3a087aa20a_FormControl0_V1_I1_B3").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
IE.document.getElementById("ID_Of_Your_Element").Click
```

If your case, you can use:

```
HTMLDOC.getElementById("ctl00_ctl40_g_07433f93_b974_4a29_9e53_cc3a087aa20a_FormControl0_V1_I1_B3").Click
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for commenting. I have tried your suggestion and while it clicks the submit button, when i go back to the site and check for the update, it does not update the value.

Comment: What is the website? Are you able to share it?

Comment: Sorry, it's a work sharepoint url so can't share it.

Comment: Give this a try. HTMLDOC.getElementById("Your_Id_Here").getElementsByTag‌​Name("input")(0).Click This assumes there is only one submit button on the page (because of the 0 in parentheses) and the tag name is "input".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but sadly the inputed data doesn't stay once page is refreshed upon save.

Comment: Too bad! I've got two more suggestions, though. HTMLDOC.forms(0).submit OR HTMLDOC.querySelector("input[type=submit]").Click.

Comment: Thanks again. no go on those lines.  The original code only seems to work if I pause break before the final click/submit.  It is as if the IE needs to be focused on front, but I do take that into account on the 2nd to last line of .focus.  This has really left me puzzled. i was looking into using a mouse tap event to control the clicks on the mouse, but i am not sure if these .click options are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation yet to post comments.
You need to slow down when doing automation.  Try using my [Pause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66237128/15225642)() subroutine after every line interacting with the HTMLDOC.  Start with 2 seconds and reduce gradually while testing for reliability. Something like the following (not tested).

A better way to automate browsers with VBA is with Selenium. I recommend watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jZGhKugK70) excellent tutorial by Gove Allen.

```
Sub test()
   Const SPEED = 2.0 'reduce 
   url = "Sharepoint - hidden"

   Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
   IE.Visible = True: Pause SPEED
   IE.Navigate url: Pause 5
    
    
   Dim HTMLDOC As HTMLDocument

   Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
   Do
   Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

   Set HTMLDOC = IE.Document

   Dim sCntrl1 as string: sCntrl1 = "ctl00_ctl40_g_07433f93_b974_4a29_9e53_cc3a087aa20a_FormControl0_V1_I1_T5"
   Dim sCntrl2 as string: sCntrl2 = "ctl00_ctl40_g_07433f93_b974_4a29_9e53_cc3a087aa20a_FormControl0_V1_I1_B3"
   HTMLDOC.all.Item(sCntrl1).innerText = "New Employee - Test:" & Now() : Pause SPEED
   HTMLDOC.all.Item(sCntrl1).Focus : Pause SPEED
   HTMLDOC.all.Item(sCntrl2).Click : Pause SPEED
End sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, while the code runs without error. the values on the webpage do not update after the page is refreshed.